# how to customize k8s nginx ingress HTTP headers error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

in our cluster,  there's a customized error pages backend and a auth service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: 'http:/***/auth'
```

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/custom-errors/
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/images/custom-error-pages

From above link and the log show in error pages backend from auth service 401, it only have 8 hardcode heades like below.

2020/04/14 03:24:35 request info &{GET /?access_token=pk1.eyJ1Ijoid2ViZXJ0YW8iLCJhIjoiY2pibTdmaWc2MTZqaDJybzFzcm93bGE2eiJ9.cwSE9DYCYP0dIeY4Hhp6Kg HTTP/1.0 1 0 map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Connection:[close] Postman-Token:[c7d07b51-5e3d-469d-9ec4-73be2cf5cd26] User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.24.0] X-Code:[401] X-Format:[*/*] X-Ingress-Name:[static-api-ingress] X-Namespace:[default] X-Original-Uri:[/xxxx/-76.9,38.9,15/1000x1000@1x?access_token=pk1.eyJ1Ijoid2ViZXJ0YW8iLCJhIjoiY2pibTdmaWc2MTZqaDJybzFzcm93bGE2eiJ9.cwSE9DYCYP0dIeY4Hhp6Kg] X-Service-Name:[static-api-svc] X-Service-Port:[80]] {}  0 [] true api.staging.versalinks.net map[] map[]  map[] 172.20.0.70:11440 /?access_token=pk1.eyJ1Ijoid2ViZXJ0YW8iLCJhIjoiY2pibTdmaWc2MTZqaDJybzFzcm93bGE2eiJ9.cwSE9DYCYP0dIeY4Hhp6Kg    0xc00009e0c0}

Is it possible we can add some customized header X-AUTH-INFO from auth service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Headers](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-headers) for nginx ingress controller via a ConfigMap to pass a custom list of headers to the upstream server.

You should define ConfigMap with your custom headers:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  X-Different-Name: "true"
  X-Request-Start: t=${msec}
  X-Using-Nginx-Controller: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-headers
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

> This defines a ConfigMap in the `ingress-nginx` namespace named `custom-headers`, holding several custom X-prefixed HTTP headers.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-set-headers: "ingress-nginx/custom-headers"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

> This defines a ConfigMap in the `ingress-nginx` namespace named `nginx-configuration`. This controls the [global configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md) of the ingress controller, and already exists in a standard installation. The key `proxy-set-headers` is set to cite the previously-created `ingress-nginx/custom-headers` ConfigMap.
>
> The nginx ingress controller will read the `ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration` ConfigMap, find the `proxy-set-headers` key, read HTTP headers from the `ingress-nginx/custom-headers` ConfigMap, and include those HTTP headers in all requests flowing from nginx to the backends.

Comment: thanks, this kinds of Custom header will only be passed to the upstream server.  it doesn't work in my case, i need pass them to the default backend from the auth service error.